# Why do u get last number of seconds stuck after i pass 1h mark

Tags: c

I decide to make clock in C as my first "Project", Changing minutes after 60 sec mark went well but when i need to change hours after minutes my secon number of seconds wont reset so it stayis with number 9 stuck until i go to the point of 10 sec.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>

int main ()
{
   int h = 0,m = 59, s = 55;
   int prekid = 1;
        while (prekid == 1)
        {
            printf(" \r H:%d | M: %d | S: %d",h,m,s);
            s++;
            fflush(stdout);
            if (s == 60)
            {
                m++;
                s= 0;
            }

            if (m == 60)
            {

                m = 0;
                s= 0;
                h++;
            }

            sleep(1);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please show the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for your issue: when line gets shorter, characters from previous, longer line remain on screen.

Solution 1, add enough spaces, 3 in this case I believe, at the end of format string to overwrite extra numbers:

```
printf(" \r H:%d | M: %d | S: %d   ",h,m,s);
```

Solution 2, write fixed width output, here with leading zeroes:

```
printf(" \r H:%02d | M: %02d | S: %02d",h,m,s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Rathe than print a variable width of text (and leave lefts-overs that caused OP's troubles), print a fixed width:

```
// printf(" \r H:%d | M: %d | S: %d",h,m,s);
printf("\r H:%2d | M:%2d | S:%2d", h, m, s);
```

`"%2d"` directs `printf()` to print at least 2 characters, padding on the left with spaces as needed.